# Calculate monthly percent

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math, accounting

In credit system, client take a debt money for %3 monthly and he must pay **same monthly debt** in every month to close his debt.

I need to find that **same monthly debt** in every month. I can not find that, how they find the `221.02`. I have one sample:

```
Amount = 2200
Month count = 12 month  
Monthly percent = 3 %
```

In this case we get this table:

```
     amount      %3 percent      net debt       monthly debt
 1.    2200          66.00         155.02           221.02
 2.    2044.98       61.34         159.67           221.02 
 3.    1885          56.55         164.46           221.02
 4.    1720.85       51.62         169.39           221.02
 5.    ......        .....         ......           221.02
 .........................................................
 12.   214.54        6.43          214.54           221.02
```

In this sample, client pays `221.02` for every month and after 12 month debt finishs. Calculations is like this:

For fist month, we find `(2200*3/100)=66` and `221.02-66 = 155.02`.
In second month: `2200-155.02 = 2044.98` and continues.

We see in example,

```
For 2200 amount, for 12 months, monthly debt is 221.02. 
For 2200 amount, for 6 months, which monthly debt will we get?
```

Generally, if we know amount, percent and month count, how can we calculate monthly debt (same value in every month) in c#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're looking for [amortization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_%28business%29)

Comment: You do know algos are language independent? You calculate it in C# by the same algorithm you do it in C++, C, Pascal, Java and any other langauge. THis is standard financial math - and if you work in this area, better grab a book with ALL the formulas relevant so you know what you do. Helps to read it.

Comment: @TomTom: then you are saying that `language` in this case is actually irrelevant? If I understand correctly, I agree.

Comment: I know, it does not depend on language. Thanks

Comment: I agree, I noted C#, because, if someone wants write in code, will write in c#.

Comment: Need to clean up the question.  A credit is used to pay off a debt.  Given a debt, interest, and number of months you want the fixed monthly payment (credit) to pay off the debt.   I think this is a form of present value calculation.

Comment: Blam, if you have a time, you can clean up my question, please, my english is not good, so, I tried to explain my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series of payments at regular intervals is an annuity. The division of a sum into such is called amortization. To determine the fixed amount, divide the sum by the present value of the annuity.

Here's how you can calculate the present value of an immediate annuity at interest `i` per period over `n` periods in Clojure, a functional language.

```lisp
(defn pv-annuity [i n] 
  (let [v (/ 1 (+ 1 i))] 
    (apply + (take n (iterate (partial * v) v)))))
```

This says, the present value is the sum of the present value of each payment, `1/(1+i), 1/(1+i)^2, 1/(1+i)^3, ..., 1/(1+i)^n`.

The desired fixed payment is then

```lisp
(/ 2200 (pv-annuity 0.03 12))
;=> 221.0165880405186
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for

[Financial.Pmt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.pmt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If not look in the Financial class